# polymer - How to pass data to an element view

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

So this might be a difficult question to understand, but essentially I am trying to pass a value to another view of my polymer app.

**secrets-app.html**

```
<a on-tap="_loadHuddle" name="{{item.$key}}" href="#/view2" >[[item.$key]]</a>

<iron-pages
    id="pages"
    selected="[[page]]"
    attr-for-selected="name"
    fallback-selection="view404"
    role="main">
  <my-view1 name="view1" route="{{route}}"></my-view1>
  <my-view2 name="view2" route="{{route}}" secret="{{secret}}"></my-view2>
  <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
</iron-pages>

<script>
  properties: {
    secret: {
      type: String,
      value: ''
    }
  },
  _loadHuddle: function(e) {

    var clickedElement = e.target;

    // magically get data from the list menu item clicked!
    var item = this.$.messages.itemForElement(e.target);
    console.log("item", item)

    this.set('secret', item["which"]);


    console.log("loading huddle");
    this.set('route.path', '/view2');
    // this.$.pages.select("view2");
    this.$.drawer.close();

  },
</script>
```

When I click the `a` tag I want to be able to store the "secret" and send it to view2. My understanding is that I should be able to access this through `this.secret` but this is not the case.

I have a `_secrets` observer in **my-view2.html** that gets called when `this.secrets` is set but then something with the `route.path` makes `this.secret = undefined`. I need this defined so I can eventually make the right query to firebase.

This is like my first week with polymer so still learning, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you reduce your code with the problem to a working sample, and put it into github? That would help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that it's because you're using a  tag. Try changing it to another tag, like , and it will start to work.

Other than that, you can save variables in localStorage or even in the window object.